# Find combination of items in the same line in one file text and thei frequency

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have one file text, two lists of terms.

```
file = "the workers have human rights, the women have rights, the people have to work."

list1 = ['workers, rights']
list2 = ['have', 'the']
```

What needed is to find if one item in list1 and one item in list2 are in the same line in the file, and calcolate their frequency at the level of the file text. I tried the following code, but it does not give the correct frequency.

```
freq = 0
result = []
for line in file.splitlines():
    for i in list1:
            for x in list2:
                    if i in line and x in line:
                            freq +=1
                            result.append((i,x, freq))
```

Comment: Are `workers` and `rights` intended to be separate strings?

Comment: yes they are separate strings

Comment: In this code, one line can have multiple matches (e.g line 1 contains all possibilities). Shall this be counted as one or as for in your varible freq?

Comment: this can be counted as one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
import itertools

frequencies = {}
for line in open_file: # You don't need .splitlines() to iterate, and you shouldn't use file as a name
    line = line.strip().split()
    list1_used = (x for x in list1 if x in line)
    list2_used = (x for x in list2 if x in line)
    for combination in itertools.product(list1_used, list2_used):
        frequencies[combination] = frequencies.get(combination, 0) + 1
```

This will create a dictionary of the frequencies for each pair.  For example, you might get something like `{('rights', 'have'): 1, ('workers', 'have'): 1, ('rights', 'the'): 1, ('workers', 'the'): 1}` if the line you gave were the only line in the file object.  If you want to take into consideration how many times a given word shows up, it's a little more complicated for `list1_used` and `list2_used`:

```
list1_used = sum((((x,) * line.count(x)) for x in list1), ())
list2_used = sum((((y,) * line.count(y)) for y in list2), ())
```

It might be easier to use `defaultdict` here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

frequencies = defaultdict(int)
for line in open_file:
    line = line.strip().split()
    list1_used = ...
    list2_used = ...
    for combination in itertools.product(list1_used, list2_used):
        frequencies[combination] += 1
```

Comment: One may use `frequencies = defaultdict(int)` here for increased elegance (gives `frequencies[combination] += 1`).

Comment: Thanks.  I added it.